# formatting data.table output

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data.tables each with 10+ columns consisting of ~4 key (columns) and the remaining value (counts) columns. When printing to a log file, I would like to print the keys as-is while the values should be formatted.  For example

```
require(data.table)
NF <- function(x) { return(format(x,big.mark=",",trim=TRUE,scientific=FALSE)) }

dt <- data.table(c1=c("a","b"),c2=c("c","d"),c3=c("e","f"),c4=c(123456,432156),
              c5=c(4839384,83473948))
cbind(dt[, 1:3, with=F], dt[, lapply(.SD,NF), .SDcols=4:5])  #desired output
```

How can I write this without needing to cbind and make two calls to dt?  I do not want to persist the formatted values
in the data.table.  It is only for the log file.  My tables are large and I would prefer not to copy them.

Comment: And why not "persist" them? You can drop them with `:= NULL` instantaneously afterwards. And if that's hitting your memory limits (which seems unlikely), maybe note that you don't actually need to format all rows if you're just looking at console output, which prints 10 rows by default (five from the top and bottom)...

Comment: In your specific example, all the numeric columns are formatted, so you could just apply the format function to _all_ columns as `df[,lapply(.SD,NF)]`.  This may not help in with your actual problem, in which case you should update your example to reflect that (i.e. add a numerical column which you don't want to be formatted).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
#example data
blah <- data.table(a=letters[1:10], b=letters[3:12], c=letters[5:14],
            d=c(1:7,12,32,13)*1000, e=c(1,5,6,7,8,3,2,5,1,4)*1000)
#define key values
indx <- c('a','b','c')

write.csv(blah[,lapply(.SD, function(x) { 
  format(x,big.mark = ',',trim=TRUE, scientific = FALSE)}), 
  .SDcols=names(blah)[!names(blah)%in%indx],by=indx],
  file='yourfile.csv')
```

Comment: perhaps the use of `data.table::fwrite` instead of `write.csv` could be a litle faster?